# Generic reference for object

Tags: java, generics

I've a code where a Object implementing a certain interface (ChallengeTransactionInfo) should be deserialized from a JSON String in order to be processed. The processos also implements a certain interface(ChallengeTransactionAction), which is bound to the first interface:

```
public interface ChallengeTransactionInfo {
}

public interface ChallengeTransactionAction<T extends ChallengeTransactionInfo> {
    public Class<T> getTransactionInfoClass();
    public void setTrxInfo(T trxInfo);
}
```

Then I have two classes that implement those interfaces

```
public class TestAVO implements ChallengeTransactionInfo {
}

public class TestAAction implements ChallengeTransactionAction<TestAVO>{

    public Class<TestAVO> getTransactionInfoClass() {
        return TestAVO.class;
    }

    public void setTrxInfo(TestAVO trxInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And now I have a code that receives the action, the JSON string, and should deserialize the Info object and pass it to the Action object

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChallengeTransactionAction<? extends ChallengeTransactionInfo> action = (ChallengeTransactionAction<? extends ChallengeTransactionInfo>) null;

        ChallengeTransactionInfo rsaTrxInfo = null;

        Class<? extends ChallengeTransactionInfo> rsaTrxClazz = null;

        rsaTrxClazz = action.getTransactionInfoClass();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        String objectJSON = "{one:1}";

        // And we retrieve it
        rsaTrxInfo = gson.fromJson(objectJSON, rsaTrxClazz);

        //setTransactionInfoClass
        action.setTrxInfo(rsaTrxInfo);
    }
}
```

This code does not compile, as the call to setTrxInfo gives an error:

The method setTrxInfo(capture#5-of ? extends ChallengeTransactionInfo) in the type ChallengeTransactionAction is not applicable for the arguments (ChallengeTransactionInfo)

So the problem is that rsaTrxInfo should be defined somehow as
? extends ChallengeTransactionInfo rsaTrxInfo

But it does not work. How can I create a generic reference in order for this to work?

Comment: what happens if you just write `ChallengeTransactionAction action` and  `Class> rsaTrxClazz`?

Comment: Well, that compiles, and it should work. But it is a bit ugly.

Comment: Why ugly? What's the need of repeating `<? extends ChallengeTransactionInfo>`  anyways? That's what the class signature states already, adding that in your field declaration just adds meaningless complexity.